# It is dangerous to clean the cache in a project in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, caching

I am new in Symfony2 and I am working in a project in the prod environment.

I changed a twig file so it looks like I have to clean the cache to update the page.

There is any risk at cleaning the cache of the project?
It is possible that I am going to lost any important file?
If yes, there is a way to make this update of some safer way?

Comment: You may have permission issue if not cleaning the cache in a proper way, resulting in a fatal error. You could clean it with the web server user (apache, nginx...) with the regular command line : `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` or just deleting the files in the `app/cache/prod` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it can be dangerous. No, there's no safer way. You should take a backup of the whole application root (cache included).

## Details

The `cache` folder contains "compiled" files. Unless someone is doing something very wrong, it does not contains important files. And - even if it does - it would probably be quite complex to get them out from cache.

So at first glance you should be able to delete the cache anytime you want without fear.

### Cache version

There's a small catch: you cannot be sure that - even before your changes - the current cache is sync with the current source code.

If, previously, someone made changes to the application but **did not clear the cache**, those changes are not actually used in production.

In this case, when you clear the cache all such changes will be released as well as your change.

### Suggestion

Right now the only way is forward, so you have to clear the cache. But you may want to:

- backup first
- get a list of more recent changes to source code
- do the task when you have time to test and fix if something comes up

In the long term, you should use a deploy script / system to make sure that the cache is automatically cleared any time some changes to source code is delivered.